# How do I access nested JSON data in android using java?

Tags: java, android, json

If my JSON object looks something like this:

```
{
 "weather:{
   "sunny": "yes"
   "wind": "48mph"
   "location":{
     "city": "new york"
     "zip": "12345"
   }
 }
 "rating": "four stars"
}
```

How would I access the city name? I can use optString to get all of "weather" or "rating" but how do I get info that's inside that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject weather = jsonObj.getJSONObject("weather");
JSONObject location = weather.getJSONObject("location");
String city = location.getString("city");
```

Read up on [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(yourdata); 
JSONObject weather = json.getString("weather");
weather.getString("sunny"); //yes
weather.getString("wind"); //46mph

JSONObject location = new JSONObject(weather.getString("location"));
location.getString("city"); // new york

json.getString("rating"); //...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject weatherObj = obj.getJSONObject("weather");
JSONObject locationObj = weatherObj.getJSONObject("location");
String city = locationObj.getString("city"); //new york
```